# Problem validating array filter time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I wrote a program that searches the array and displays the content on the console
I want to first do the validation in the input that I wrote to show the results if it is valid and if it is not valid or has no result, the search will show the aleart message
But unfortunately the program of the if part is not done properly, please help me

*Please test the app and see the problem*

```js
this.array = [{
    name: "nadiya",
    phone: 123456
  }, {
    name: "amir",
    phone: 123456
  },
  {
    name: "niloufar",
    phone: 123456
  }, {
    name: "arman",
    phone: 123456
  },
  {
    name: "sara",
    phone: 123456
  }, {
    name: "pariya",
    phone: 123456
  }
];
const self = this;
const selectID = (idName) => document.getElementById(idName);

this.search = function() {
  function filterArray() {
    const selectInput = document.getElementById("inputSearch").value;
    const validStr = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    const validInpout = selectInput.length >= 2
    const result = self.array.filter((obj) => {
      return obj.name.toUpperCase().includes(selectInput.toUpperCase())
    });
    if (selectInput.value === validInpout && validInpout) {
      if (result.length <= 0) {
        alert("Contact not found")
      } else {
        return result;
      }
    } else {
      alert("To search, it must be more than 2 characters and use letters")
    }
  }
  return filterArray();
};
this.showResultSearch = function() {
  const searchResult = self.search();
  searchResult.forEach((ele) => {
    console.log(`name: ${ele.name} phone: ${ele.phone}`);
  });
};
this.startSearch = function() {
  console.clear();
  this.showResultSearch();
};
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="inputSearch">
  <button type="button" id="BtnSearch" onclick="startSearch()">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `selectInput.lenght` should be `.length`

Comment: `filterArray()` also returns nothing (if the result isn't valid), so `searchResult` is undefined and you get a TypeError when trying to loop over it

Comment: @chazsolo Yes, dear friend, you are right. I am very tired :D

Comment: `&& /^[A-Za-z]+$/` does nothing in your attempt to validate - you need to test it against the value

Comment: @chazsolo I modified my code but it still does not work. The problem is something else

Comment: @chazsolo Help me please

Comment: @chazsolo Dear friend, you edited my code but it does not work, please test

Comment: I've fixed your code snippet but there are still some basic things you need to understand. `selectInput` _is_ the value of the input, yet you are still using `selectInput.value` later. `validInpout` (sic) is a boolean, but you are trying to test it against (what should be) a string. You also still don't return anything from `this.search` if there is no match, so the TypeError for `.forEach` is still there.

Comment: You also don't need `this` in front of your variables? Unless this is just part of a module or class.

Comment: @chazsolo It is possible, please correct my code errors. The program will work and I will learn what to do to fix the problem. I am a little confused.

Comment: @chazsolo Yes, `this` is part of my other code and I need the word

Comment: @chazsolo If you have the opportunity, please help me :) I need `this` I do not want to be removed from the program I just want validation to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of issues - see comments to your question

Additionally:

I return immediately there is no input

I only search if valid input

Note "this" here is "window" in this code

Also pressing enter on the field will submit the form. It is simpler to make the button a submit and use the form submit event

```js
this.array = [{
    name: "nadiya",
    phone: 123456
  }, {
    name: "amir",
    phone: 123456
  },
  {
    name: "niloufar",
    phone: 123456
  }, {
    name: "arman",
    phone: 123456
  },
  {
    name: "sara",
    phone: 123456
  }, {
    name: "pariya",
    phone: 123456
  }
];
const self = this;
const selectID = (idName) => document.getElementById(idName);

this.search = function() {
  const selectInput = document.getElementById("inputSearch").value.trim();
  const validStr = /[A-Za-z]{2,}/;
  const validInput = validStr.test(selectInput);
  if (!validInput) alert("To search, it must be more than 2 characters and use letters")
  else {
    const result = self.array.filter((obj) => {
      return obj.name.toUpperCase().includes(selectInput.toUpperCase())
    });
    if (result.length === 0) {
      alert("Contact not found")
    } else {
      return result;
    }
  }

};
this.showResultSearch = function() {
  const searchResult = self.search();
  if (searchResult && searchResult.length > 0) searchResult.forEach((ele) => {
    console.log(`name: ${ele.name} phone: ${ele.phone}`);
  });
};
this.startSearch = function() {
  console.clear();
  this.showResultSearch();
};
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="inputSearch">
  <button type="button" id="BtnSearch" onclick="startSearch()">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I added the test too

Comment: Can you please help me with this question ?! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67114097/is-not-defined-function-at-the-time-of-click

Comment: Sorry no. I do not see the issue easily. Also you call the search onload.